# Windows update slows XP Boot

Tags: windows, windows-update

After installing this week's (2/9/10) Windows Update, XP rebooted a few times before finally stabilizing. Now XP takes about twice as long to boot as it did before the update. I have read that many XP users are getting blue screen on boots after this update. Does anybody know how to fix this without rolling back all the updates? Is this a cruel trick to get me to move to Windows 7?  :-)

Comment: "Is this a cruel trick to get me to move to Windows 7?" I wouldn't put this past Microsoft! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Microsoft has pulled that patch from windows update, but if you're still having issues, [this](http://www.krebsonsecurity.com/2010/02/new-patches-cause-bsod-for-some-windows-xp-users/) should help.

Answer (score 0):

My HP/Compaq NC6320 XP Pro SP 3 laptop is giving me a blank blue screen for 15 minutes before completing the boot process. During this time, I can access Task Manager with Ctrl + Alt + Delete, but it doesn't give me any clue of what is happening. I uninstalled all of the Feb 10 updates, but this has not changed the problem.

My next move is to fit my backup HD, and hope that it boots ok. If so, then I can work from there to restore my current data files from other backups.